# Refused connection to Oracle Database with JAVA

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I'm trying to connect to a remote Oracle BD with JAVA. Firstly, I connected with a OracleDataSource, of this way:

```
OracleDataSource fdo = new OracleDataSource();
fdo.setDatabaseName("orc1");
fdo.setDriverType("thin");
fdo.setServerName("150....");
fdo.setPortNumber(1521);
con = fdo.getConnection("...", "...");
```

The connection is OK.

But now, I new to connect directly with the Oracle Driver.
I did this:

```
DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@150....:1521/orc1","....","....");
Statement s = con.createStatement();    
ResultSet result = s.executeQuery("select *from MRALOGIN");
while(result.next()){
    System.out.println(result.getString(1));
}
```

But this produce the next exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
    ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in 
    connect descriptor
```

Somebody knows why? The service orc1 exists, the host direction is valid...I tested with the `OracleDataSource` connection.

Comment: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2398370?tstart=0 ...this may be useful for u

Comment: Try `jdbc:oracle:thin:@//150....:1521/orc1` instead

Comment: I tried too but the result was the same

Comment: Another try: `jdbc:oracle:thin:@150....:1521:orc1`

Comment: I tried too. In this case, the exception is this:java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Error de E/S: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Comment: Is it really `orc1`, with a one at the end, not `orcl` with an ell? If that is right, is it the SID, or the service name, or both? The syntax you're using expects the service name. `lsnrctl services` will confirm the actual service name. But then, Egor's version should work if that is the SID.

Comment: this is the propierties panel of my oracle connection: http://imageshack.com/a/img713/8830/0hgg.jpg

Comment: I believe you've put in `orc1`; I'm querying if it *should* be `orcl` *8-) Also your query, when you get as far as executing it, need a space between the `*` and `from`.

Comment: You can see that when i connect with the Oracle BD manually, the SID name is orc1, with a one. And I tried with the space between * and from, but the result is the same: ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor :(

Comment: @user3118887 - I can see that's what you've put in the question, but I can't tell if you've cut-and-pasted that or retyped it. More importantly the `setDatabaseName()` value is the SID, while the URL format you used expects the service name, and they are not necessarily the same. Adding the output of `lsnrctl services` to the question (not as a comment) would clarify things (and probably shut me up *8-) Only other obvious possibility is that the `150...` address you've masked is different, but you'd have noticed that by now.